# in F#, How do you merge 2 Collections.Map instances?

Tags: collections, f#

I am trying to merge two Maps, but there is no built in method for joining Collections. So how do you do it?

Comment: you should look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590991/merging-two-ienumerablets), basically  map1.Union(map2) should work

Comment: Slight quibble: using linq's Union operator you'd end up with a IEnumerable of tuples, not quite the same as a map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
let join (p:Map<'a,'b>) (q:Map<'a,'b>) = 
    Map(Seq.concat [ (Map.toSeq p) ; (Map.toSeq q) ])
```

example:

```
let a = Map([1,11;2,21;3,31;])

let b = Map([3,32; 4,41;5,51;6,61;])

let c = join a b
```

and the result:

```
val c : Map<int,int> =
  map [(1, 11); (2, 21); (3, 32); (4, 41); (5, 51); (6, 61)]
```

Comment: Be aware that this reconstructs both maps from scratch which can be very slow. A better solution is Robert's if `map1` is large and `map2` is small.

Answer (score 32):

You can implement this using Map.fold and Map.add, since add is actually add/replace:

```
let map1 = Map.ofList [ 1, "one"; 2, "two"; 3, "three" ]
let map2 = Map.ofList [ 2, "two"; 3, "oranges"; 4, "four" ]


let newMap = Map.fold (fun acc key value -> Map.add key value acc) map1 map2

printfn "%A" newMap
```

Probably the reason merge isn't provided out of the box is that you need to deal with key conflicts. In this simple merge algorithm we simple take the key value pair from the second map, this may not be the behaviour you want.

Comment: Indeed this was exactly how I implemented this:

Answer (score 15):

An alternative way is this:

```
let merge (a : Map<'a, 'b>) (b : Map<'a, 'b>) (f : 'a -> 'b * 'b -> 'b) =
    Map.fold (fun s k v ->
        match Map.tryFind k s with
        | Some v' -> Map.add k (f k (v, v')) s
        | None -> Map.add k v s) a b
```

It lets you decide on what value you want if there is duplicate keys.

Example:

```
let a = Map([1,11;2,21;3,31;])

let b = Map([3,32; 4,41;5,51;6,61;])

merge a b (fun k (v, v') -> v + v');;

//Result
val it : Map<int,int> =
  map [(1, 11); (2, 21); (3, 63); (4, 41); (5, 51); (6, 61)]
```

Notice that the key `3` is different.

Comment: Note: you don't actually need to specify the types on your input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using function composition you could define a `join` function like this:

```ml
let join (m1:Map<'a,'b>) (m2:Map<'a,'b>) = 
    Map.foldBack Map.add m2 m1
```

Given that `m1` and `m2` are Maps you would then use it like this:

```ml
m3 = join m1 m2
```

Some caveats:

- Keys in `m2` will overwrite those in `m1`
- As others have noted it's faster to let the smaller map be the second argument as it will result in fewer insertions