# Problem merging IEnumerable<T> using Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I have 2 IEnumerables which are of type 'Product' - totalProducts and ProductsChosen. As the names suggest totalProducts holds all the products available and ProductsChosen holds the products chosen by the user .

The Product class has properties `Id` ,`number`, and `IEnumerable<AdditonalOptions> options`.

I am trying to merge these 2 IEnumerables like this

```
public IEnumerable<Product> MergeProducts(IEnumerable<Product> Products, IEnumerable<Product> ProductsChosen)
{
    return ProductsChosen.Concat(Products.Where(r => !ProductsChosen.Any(x => x.ProductId.Equals(r.ProductId))));
}
```

I have used the code to merge from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590991/merging-two-ienumerablets)

This code works fine only if I consider the product ids but I would also like to merge the `IEnumerable<AdditionalOption> options` of the `productsChosen` with that of the `totalProducts` if the Product Ids are same.But I am not sure how to do that.

Could someone please help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `Union()` method instead - although the concat was the accepted answer, as you'll see by the votes, the Union is preferred

Comment: Improved tag list to attract more views

Comment: I am thinking that this question needs clarification. My interpretation is that you are looking find the union of the two collections of `Products` and on the intersection of the `Products` in that result you want the union of the `AdditionalOptions`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

As the chosen products have different options that the total products they must be distinct instances. Since you have said that total products are all that are available then I assume that the set of chosen product ids must be a subset of the product ids.

Also, since the chosen products are distinct instances then it is possible that there may be zero or more chosen products per each total product so my solution works for this case too. It will equally work if there are only zero or one.

Further, since they are distinct instances *and* the `options` property is an `IEnumerable` it made sense to me to create a new set of instances for the merged products so as to not alter the original set of total products.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> MergeProducts(
    IEnumerable<Product> Products,
    IEnumerable<Product> ProductsChosen)
{
    return
        from p in Products
        join pc in ProductsChosen on p.Id equals pc.Id into pcs
        select new Product()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            number = p.number,
            options = p.options
                .Concat(
                    from pc2 in pcs
                    from ao in pc2.options
                    select ao).ToArray(),
        };
}
```

You didn't explain what `number` property is, so I've just done a simple assignment for this value from the `Products` list and ignored this value from the `ProductsChosen` list.

Also, you didn't say how the `AdditionalOptions` needed to be merged. This is no `Merge` method for enumerables. You need to use something like `Concat` or `Union` to do a merge. I've chosen `Concat` but that easy to change.

Does this work for you?