# Merge two IEnumerable with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got the following class

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    (...)
}
```

And I have the following `IEnumerable<Application>`:

```
IEnumerable<Application> applications1 = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 1},
    new Application {Id = 2, Version = 1},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 3}
};

IEnumerable<Application> applications2 = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 2},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 2}
    new Application {Id = 4, Version = 1}
};
```

How can I merge them into a single `IEnumerable<Application>` using LINQ while ensuring that if two `Applications` have the same `Id` only the one with the highest `Version` is added to the new `IEnumerable<Application>`, effectively my final `IEnumerable should be equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<Application> final = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 2},
    new Application {Id = 2, Version = 1},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 3},
    new Application {Id = 4, Version = 1}
}
```

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski That won´t do anything on the `Version`. Thus it´s completely random which of the two versions will survive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining 2 lists and and remove duplicates .Output in a third list .My attempts do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682437/combining-2-lists-and-and-remove-duplicates-output-in-a-third-list-my-attempts)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that doesn't really answer my question because his objects are _actually_ equal, mine aren't, but thx for bringing it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two IEnumerable<T>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590991/merging-two-ienumerablets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) combined with selecting maximum in group via [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1):

```
IEnumerable<Application> final = applications1
    .Concat(applications2)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate((acc, curr) => acc.Version > curr.Version ? acc: curr))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A more procedural way would be:

```
var concat = applications1.Concat(applications2)
    .ToArray();

var final = concat
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    .Select (g => new
    {
        ApplicationId = g.Key,
        MaxVersion = g.Max(i => i.Version)
    })
    .Select(i => concat.FirstOrDefault(
        existing => existing.Id == i.ApplicationId && 
                    existing.Version == i.MaxVersion))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why just don't write something like that?

```cs
var result = applications1
    .Concat(applications2).GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => new Application { Id = g.Key, Version = g.Max(a => a.Version) });
```

You concatenate both collections, group items by `Id`, then select new `Application` instance with group key as an `Id` and max `Version`.

If you don't want to create a new `Application` instance, the following code might help, by looking a max `Version` for every group and return an `Application` with max `Version` value

```cs
var result = applications1
    .Concat(applications2).GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var maxVersion = g.Max(a => a.Version);
        return g.First(a => a.Version == maxVersion);
    });
```

Comment: I know this would work in the example given, but it assumes that the class only has two properties and both have a setter, so that a new object may be constructed. This is unfortunately not quite the case here. I'm still upvoting because it does work in the example given given

Comment: @cogumel0 Yes, I assuming your example. If there are more properties here, you should consider how to manage them - add to grouping, use the first/last/average/max and so on

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I think there are better ways that don't involve recreating the objects.

Comment: @cogumel0 Got your point, I've added another code snippet, which doesn't require recreating of objects